# iscsiadm: cannot make connection to <IP>: No route to host

Tags: networking, ping, route, iscsi

when I try iscsiadm discovery:

```
iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p <IP>
```

I get this error:

```
iscsiadm: cannot make connection to <IP>: No route to host
```

however, I can ping the IP fine.

I have added following rule in `route`:

```
ip route add <IP>/32 via 10.10.10.1 dev eth1
```

and i can confirm that ping pings through `eth1` interface:

```
ping -I eth1 <IP>
```

but for some reason, it looks as if `iscsiadm` is not using my `route` settings ?

and `traceroute` works as well:

```
# traceroute <IP>
traceroute to <IP>, 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.10.10.1  0.555 ms  0.776 ms  0.973 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  myhost (<IP>)  0.714 ms !X  0.657 ms !X  0.674 ms !X
```

Comment: What does `traceroute <IP>` say?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick - traceroute works. Please see my edit.

Comment: OK, routing was the first thing to check, but this error message can also be caused by iptables. Do you have rules restricting tcp input or output?

Comment: I have no firewall

Answer (score 4):

Open port from target machine. Reload firewall

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=3260/tcp --permanent
systemctl reload firewalld
```